# How do I convert certain columns of a data frame to become factors?

Tags: r, numeric, r-factor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [identifying or coding unique factors using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798206/identifying-or-coding-unique-factors-using-r)

I'm having some trouble with R.

I have a data set similar to the following, but much longer.

```
A B Pulse
1 2 23
2 2 24
2 2 12
2 3 25
1 1 65
1 3 45
```

Basically, the first 2 columns are coded. `A` has 1, 2 which represent 2 different weights.
`B` has 1, 2, 3 which represent 3 different times.

As they are coded numerical values, R will treat them as numerical variables.
I need to use the factor function to convert these variables into factors.

Help?

Answer (score 59):

Here's an example:

```
#Create a data frame
> d<- data.frame(a=1:3, b=2:4)
> d
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4

#currently, there are no levels in the `a` column, since it's numeric as you point out.
> levels(d$a)
NULL

#Convert that column to a factor
> d$a <- factor(d$a)
> d
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4

#Now it has levels.
> levels(d$a)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

You can also handle this when reading in your data. See the `colClasses` and `stringsAsFactors` parameters in e.g. `readCSV()`.

Note that, computationally, factoring such columns won't help you much, and may actually slow down your program (albeit negligibly). Using a factor will require that all values are mapped to IDs behind the scenes, so any print of your data.frame requires a lookup on those levels -- an extra step which takes time.

Factors are great when storing strings which you don't want to store repeatedly, but would rather reference by their ID. Consider storing a more friendly name in such columns to fully benefit from factors.

Comment: But each of the numbers represents something. For A, 1 represents long, and 2 represents short. For B, 1 2 3 represents, 1kg, 2kg, 3kg So I need to convert all those 1's, 2's etc into the 1kg, 2kg, long, short etc. I need to add labels to them.

Comment: Try running the code above followed by assigning the `levels` value to something more useful. For instance, `levels(d$a) <- c("Long", "Short")`. Now you (or a new user looking at your code) needn't worry about memorizing the mappings between your IDs and your labels. R will handle the mapping for you and just present the labels to you.

Comment: Jeff is a more complete solution because it adds the levels in the same command.

Answer (score 33):

Given the following sample

```
myData <- data.frame(A=rep(1:2, 3), B=rep(1:3, 2), Pulse=20:25)
```

then

```
myData$A <-as.factor(myData$A)
myData$B <-as.factor(myData$B)
```

or you could select your columns altogether and wrap it up nicely:

```
# select columns
cols <- c("A", "B")
myData[,cols] <- data.frame(apply(myData[cols], 2, as.factor))

levels(myData$A) <- c("long", "short")
levels(myData$B) <- c("1kg", "2kg", "3kg")
```

To obtain

```
> myData
      A   B Pulse
1  long 1kg    20
2 short 2kg    21
3  long 3kg    22
4 short 1kg    23
5  long 2kg    24
6 short 3kg    25
```