# R convert data to factor will corrupt all other data.frame columns

Tags: r

I have a data.frame, all columns are numeric. I want to convert one integer column to factor, but doing so will convert all other columns to class character. Is there anyway to just convert one column to factor?

The example is from [Converting variables to factors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613913/converting-variables-to-factors-in-r):

```
myData <- data.frame(A=rep(1:2, 3), B=rep(1:3, 2), Pulse=20:25)
myData$A <-as.factor(myData$A)
```

The result

```
apply(myData,2,class)
#           A           B       Pulse 
# "character" "character" "character"
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) 
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit) 

locale: [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8  
attached base packages: 
[1] splines stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base ... 

str(myData$A)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: Works for me. What is your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: That seems unlikely. Does the code you provided actually reproduce the problem for you?

Comment: The only time I know of this happening is if `myData` is a matrix or array or vector, not a dataframe. are you sure `class(myData)` is a dataframe (for whichever data is causing you the problem)?

Comment: `class(myData) ` is `data.frame`. `apply(myData,2,class)` produces A           B       Pulse 
"character" "character" "character"

Comment: @Pascal `sessionInfo()` gives `R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

...  `

Comment: @MattO'Brien `str(myData$A)` gives `Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 1 2 1 2`

Comment: Use `sapply(myData, class)`, not `apply(myData,2,class)` You are testing the class of the column names.

Comment: Thank you @Pascal! using `sapply` is working.

Comment: @Pascal OP isn't testing the class of the column names, just try `apply(myData, 2, print)` compared to `sapply(myData, print)` and you'll see. See Thelas generous edit on the provided very partial anwser

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, I know. The the OP wasn't doing what he thought he was doing. After, it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works when I test it.

This is my output from `str(myData)`:

```
    'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A    : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 1 2 1 2
 $ B    : int  1 2 3 1 2 3
 $ Pulse: int  20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Your issue is because, as `?apply` states:

> ‘apply’ attempts to coerce 
>        to an array via ‘as.matrix’ if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data
>        frame)

This is done before executing the function on each column. And when you run `as.matrix(myData)` you end up with everything forced to one class, in this case character data:

```
is.character(as.matrix(myData))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @thelatemail that's quite a generous edit you made there.

Comment: @davidarenburg - I'm in my retirement Bill Gates phase now. Share the points I say.